# VS Code Screen Size

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I adjust the screen size in Visual Studio Code to ensure that my code fits perfectly without the need for horizontal scrolling, allowing me to view the entire code without using the scroll bar for left and right navigation?

I Have tried F11+Shift

Comment: Do you mean you want the font-size to dynamically adjust so the widest line of text matches the window width - or do you just want to enable line-wrapping?

Comment: This is not an on-topic question.  The fact that VSCode is used for coding does not make it so. In most applications, Ctrl+mouse-wheel or Ctrl+= and Ctrl+- will zoom in and out to fit content.

Comment: What do you call the screen size? To me it sounds like the monitor resolution, but then your question makes no sense.

Comment: @Clifford [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I agree but the question is about how to use a computer not how to code for one or even how to us a tool to build code. The zoom feature is a common UI feature shared by many applications such as Word, Excel, Chrome. I would expect that behaviour in any tool following common UI conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle word wrap using the keyboard shortcut ALT + Z on VS Code or You can set your font size accordingly under the settings User > Text Editor > Font.